# Alternative to "as-well-as" for an academic paper

Tags: phrases, formality, synonyms

Is there some better alternative to phrase  `as well as`  for an academic writing? It sounds to me too informal.

The whole sentence is:

> Improvements of both parts are possible as well as joining them into one piece of software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence, as is, does not indicate any real relationship between the 2 options other that both exist. A conjunction that showed a preference or a conditional relationship might add to the meaning and resolve your wording issue.

How about "While it is possible to improve both parts, the two can also be joined into a single piece of software." Or "The two parts may be addressed separately or may be joined into a single piece of software."

Answer (score 3):

*"and so is"* may fit better into this sentence, so the new form would be:

> Improvements of both parts are possible and so is joining them into one piece of software.

A better way to express that, though, is as follows:

> Improving both parts is possible and so is joining them into one piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

There’s nothing wrong with *as well as* in formal prose, but your sentence might be clearer written as ‘Both parts could be improved, or they could be joined into one piece of software.’

Answer (score 2):

> The two softwares can be individually improved, or made to work more cohesively as a unit.

Phrasing it this way allows for the softwares to be more integrated or re-written as a single piece of software. Monolithic architecture can be counter-productive unless the refactoring produces better modularity. But that's just me waffling on now.

Comment: This answer seems to be more concerned with architecture than with English. And I wouldn't use _softwares_.